# Printing stops at the middle of second to last layer

Tags: creality-ender-3

I just had a problem with my Ender 3 V2 Neo. It suddenly stopped printing in the middle of the second to last layer.

The head moved to the side (as if it finished printing) and the confirmation button on the screen appeared, also the progress bar was showing 100% completion but the remaining printing time was 16 minutes (of a 9-hour print). I checked and there were no clogs and no option to resume printing (at first I thought it was a power outage but it wasn't). The bed and nozzle temperature were kept at 60 °C and 200 °C as I was using PLA. I just checked the G-code and, at least to me, there are no evident problems. Also, there's no sign of over or under-extrusion on the print. I have no clue what happened.

Comment: It is great that you found a solution. However, please post your comment `Just found the problem. It was the slicer software. I was using Creality slicer and for some reason it was missing the last lines of the G-code. I installed Cura and then tried again, everything went back to normal. I have no idea why this happened. But now it's fixed. Got the hint from a reddit user.` (that you made under the, to be deleted, AI generated answer) as an *actual* answer, and not as a comment and then mark it as the accepted answer. Also, please include the link to the Reddit post (if applicable). Thanks.